# jQuery 1.5.0 to 1.5.1 breaks previous script

Tags: jquery

I needed to update my jQuery library for some bugs that IE9 has with <= v1.5.0.  Upgrading the library to 1.5.1+ (even at current 1.6.4) breaks some script that I have on the page, though... (so of course, fix one issue, cause another)...

The script allows the user to add and subtract a group of input boxes (so, if they want to input a single line item, they do just that... but they can add unlimited amount of additional line items).

```
//ADDS ANOTHER USER
$(".add-user").click(function() {
    onemore = $("#userSelectBoxes").clone();
    onemore.find(":input").each(function() {
        $(this).val("");
    });

    $("#user_block > #userSelectBoxes:last").after(onemore);
    set_add_del();
    return false;
});

$(".removeable").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    set_add_del();
    return false;
});

function set_add_del() {
    $('.remove_cat').show();
    $('.add_cat').hide();
    $('.add_cat:last').show();
    $("#user_block > #userSelectBoxes:only-child > .remove_cat").hide();
}
```

The add and remove buttons, in the HTML are as follows (and they just add another DIV of input fields basically):

```
<a href="#" class="remove_cat removeable">-</a>
<a href="#" class="add_cat add-user">+</a>
```

So with 1.5.0 - this would work properly, and let me click + or - unlimited amount of times and always function.  With 1.5.1+, I can click the + ONCE, then nothing else works (adding OR deleting).

Any ideas?  Hopefully I included all that would be needed here...

**UPDATE 9/27/11 @ 5:05 PM EST**
I followed the suggestions in the comments below.  No luck.  It actually performs exactly the same...

I should note that when I click for the 2nd time, not only does it no work (as I stated earlier), but it will pop me back up to the top of the screen as well.

Here is the latest code...

```
$(".add-user").click(function(){
                onemore = $(".userSelectBoxes").first().clone();                

                onemore.find(":input").each(function(){
                    $(this).val("");
                });

                $("#user_block > .userSelectBoxes:last").after(onemore);
                set_add_del();

                return false;
            });

            $(".removeable").click(function(){
                $(this).parent().remove();
                set_add_del();
                return false;
            });

            function set_add_del(){
            $('.remove_cat').show();
            $('.add_cat').hide();
            $('.add_cat:last').show();
            $("#user_block > .userSelectBoxes:only-child > .remove_cat").hide();
            }
```

Comment: Without going too in to detail, the blog entry detailing differences from 1.5 to 1.5.1 can be [found here](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/02/18/jquery-1-5-1-rc-1-released/).

Comment: It looks like you are ending up with multiple elements with id = `userSelectBoxes`.  That's not good.

Comment: I see an oddity you should clean up - After cloning `$("#userSelectBoxes")`, you don't give it a unique id which means you now have conflicting ID values that you later try to refer to.

Comment: @jfriend00 - hmmm I see what you mean...  what's my fix then?

Comment: @Shackrock: Use classes or an id that maybe has an incremental counter on it? Then you can check for `$('div[id^="userSelectBoxes"]');` (e.g. if #userSelectBoxes was a div)

Comment: @Shackrock you probably want to use classes instead and just clone the first one `$(".userSelectBoxes").first().clone();`

Comment: I didn't write this script... big changes are hard for me to follow... are you saying I can replace  onemore = `$("#userSelectBoxes").clone();` with `$(".userSelectBoxes").first().clone();` ?

Comment: @Shackrock: `<div id="userSelectBoxes">` might become `<div class="userSelectBoxes">`. Then, referencing it means `$('.userSelectBoxes');` (along with any CSS changes like `#userSelectBoxes {}` becomes `.userSelectBoxes {}`)

Comment: ohhhh, I see... ok... let me see what I can do here.  As far as the JS/JQuery changes, though, it just means the replacement I already said, and every `#userSelectBoxes` becomes `.userSelectBoxes`, correct?

Comment: Anyone? haha.  Sorry, I'm a little bit useless with JS...

Comment: @BradChristie I just did what you suggested, along with Dennis (using classes).  Check my updated code and results above.  Any other ideas here?  It's killing me... haha.

Comment: change `clone` to `clone(true)` to copy event handler - guessing that the 'remove' link is inside the thing that's getting duplicated? If the add button is also there this would explain everything.

Comment: @jamietre - bam!  Ok, got some functioning action now!   Please review my updated question - at the bottom.  The original script is perfect, but the 2nd script on the page now has issues as described in the edit...

Comment: Which row is supposed to be copied for the new code? What's the relationship between things with class '.one-more-time' and the add link?

Comment: @jamietre - There is a `<div id="add_ledger_entry"><span class="one-more-time"> ... </span></div>` which encompasses the entire row that I want copied.  This is the Add and Delete code: `<a href="#"  class="del_invoice removeable_invoice">-</a>  <a href="#" class="add_invoice">+</a>` - Perhaps the <div> and <span> being directly next to each other is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that class doesn't surround all the rows? Are the add/remove invoice buttons inside that span, e.g. for the row you want to copy? If so you can do something like `$(this).closest(".one-more-time")`.. to get just the one you're inside

Comment: @jamietre you know what?  I forgot to include `.first()` with the clone....ha!  That's the fix.  Thanks - you've been a huge help, along with the other people here too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different versions of jQuery on a page.  You'll need to call `.noConflict()` after loading the second version of the library.  This will reset the value of the `$` object to the first version of the library.

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();

    //'$' now refers to 1.5.0
    //'jquery' now refers to 1.5.1
</script>
```